# AWS Route Table - Terraform | An argument named "gateway_id" is not expected here

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have an internet gateway and two subnets (public and private).
While i can attach my internet gateway to the public one, i can't on the private one. I add this line in the code:

> gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.wally_jeropa_igw.id

but i have this error:

> An argument named "gateway_id" is not expected here.

This is my IGW

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "wally_jeropa_igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.wally_jeropa.id

  tags = {
    Name = "Testn IGW"
  }
}
```

Public subnet

```
resource "aws_route_table" "wally_jeropa_vpc_public_route_table" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.wally_jeropa.id
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.wally_jeropa_igw.id

    route {
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    }

    tags = {
        Name = "Public Subnet Route Table."
    }
}
```

Private subnet

```
resource "aws_route_table" "wally_jeropa_vpc_private_route_table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.wally_jeropa.id
  gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.wally_jeropa_igw.id

    tags = {
        Name = "Private Subnet Route Table."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gateway_id` attribute must be inside the route block [1]

References:

1. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route_table#route